# LLVM: Instruction does not dominate all uses

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm splitting all Basic Blocks with minimum number of instructions (usually 3-5):

```
llvm::SplitBlock(BasicBlock, &*BasicBlockiter, Pass);
```

and trying to get object file from IR

```
llc -filetype=obj 2.ll
```

I got the following errors:

```
Instruction does not dominate all uses!
  %1 = alloca i32
  %mul = load i32* %1
Instruction does not dominate all uses!
  %1 = alloca i32
  %99 = load i32* %1
```

and

```
While deleting: i32 %
Use still stuck around after Def is destroyed:  %var = alloca i32
Assertion failed: use_empty() && "Uses remain when a value is destroyed!"
```

and

```
error: expected instruction opcode
invoke.cont2:                                     ; preds = %main_block, %invoke
.cont
```

IR:

```
  invoke.cont2:                                     ; preds = %main_block, %invoke.cont
  %call4 = invoke i32 @_ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_(i32 8, i32 16)
          to label %invoke.cont3 unwind label %lpad1
  store i32 %call4, i32* %var4
```

I think that after splitting, instructions are located in different basic blocks.
If I split the block into 10-15 instructions, all is OK.
How can I predict/check and avoid this errors?

Comment: If your pass just splits basicblocks, and takes as input a correct IR file, then there is no reason to be errors of dominations in the resulting IR. There are some reason that could induce this kind of error :
* you moved or created new instructions
* you added transitions between basicblocks that did not exist before

Comment: It would help if you provided more details. A minimal LLVM IR snippet of the code *before* splitting, and then *after* splitting. In general what @JulienH. said makes sense.

Comment: I'm sorry, i have other passes and one of them add/modifies instructions via llvm::InlineAsm and llvm::ReplaceInstWithInst

Comment: What checks contained in LLVM may be added to avoid such errors?

Comment: Your post still misses details, it would help if I could see the full IR, or at least a larger subset of it... Anyway, each time you delete an instruction, you should check that this instruction has no later use (in your error message, you see there exist some use_empty() function in LLVM)

Comment: A remark that may help: invoke is a terminator instruction, meaning that it should be in the last position in a basicblock. In your case here, after the invoke, the program will jump to %invoke.cont3 (or %lpad1), but will never execute the store. I suppose that's not what you expect...

Comment: A mistake here : [`mul`](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#mul-instruction) is actually an instruction in LLVM IR, so you cannot have a variable named `%mul`. It is a reserved word in the programming langauge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first version, you had instruction after a terminator instruction, which was incorrect since this instruction is never executed.

In your second version (not mentioned here, please use stackoverflow instead of private emails...) are using %call (in the store inst) before defining it (%call = ...), so clearly your definition does not precede every use...
But as I said, the store should not be after the invoke, because invoke is a terminatorinst.

The solution is to put your store in the next basic block (you can create a new one) :

```
%invoke.cont
  %call = invoke i8* @_ZNKSs5c_strEv(%"class.std::basic_string"* @loadedFile)
          to label %invoke.cont2_before unwind label %lpad1

invoke.cont2_before:                                     ; preds = %invoke.cont
  store i8* %call, i8** %reduced_var
  br label %invoke.cont2

invoke.cont2:                                     ; preds = %main_block, %invoke.cont2_before
  %call4 = invoke i32 @_ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_(i32 8, i32 16)
          to label %invoke.cont3_before unwind label %lpad1
```

etc...

Comment: fixed, got next error:                                      The unwind destination does not have a landingpad instruction!
  invoke void @_ZNSt13basic_fstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEEC1Ev(%"class.std::basic_
fstream"* %keyStream)                                                         LandingPadInst not the first non-PHI instruction in the block.

Comment: The previous error has been fixed.The next one: Block containing
LandingPadInst must be jumped to only by the unwind edge of an
invoke. Does that mean that I cannot use br and landingpad inst
together?

Comment: That means a BasicBlock containing a LandingPadInst cannot be the destination of a BranchInst. The only way to branch to such a BasicBlock is with the unwind of an invoke.

Comment: Could you please check this file http://pastebin.com/kRWFuXV3 (original http://pastebin.com/WvkmBYiE), and explain me how I can fix the errors?

Comment: Hum, the problem seems to come from your big switch line 595, for which there are cases that branch to %lpad and %lpad1. These branches are incorrect since %lpad and %lpad1 should only be accessed from invoke instructions. You have to branch to something else here...

Comment: Errors with LandingPadInst fixed by additional check:       llvm::LandingPadInst *lpInst = idxBBPair->first->getLandingPadInst();
if(lpInst)
continue;                                                           But now i again got "instruction does not dominate all uses" http://pastebin.com/9Xi4uJJq

Comment: @Denis Please mark this post as answer, if it solved your problem.