# LLVM: Instruction does not dominate all uses - No control flow

Tags: llvm, dominate

I implemented a function pass which iterates over basic block instructions and tracks all instructions that have a type of IntegerTy.

Here is the snippet of the pass that does it:

```
if (!I->isTerminator()){
  Type::TypeID datatype = I->getType()->getTypeID();
  if (datatype == llvm::Type::IntegerTyID) {
    IRBuilder<> IRB(I);
    Value* v_value = IRB.CreateZExt(I, IRB.getInt64Ty());
    Value *args[] = {v_value};
    IRB.CreateCall(NNT_log_int, args);
  }
}
```

However the **IRB.CreateZExt(I, IRB.getInt64Ty());** command seems to create a **Instruction does not dominate all uses!** problem.

I understand the nature of the issue ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817331/llvm-instruction-does-not-dominate-all-uses-inserting-new-instruction) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832757/llvm-instruction-does-not-dominate-all-uses?rq=1) there are similar problems).

My point of confusion that I apply this pass to a toy program with no **if** statements or any other control flow statements, yet I still encounter this problem.

The error message:

```
    Instruction does not dominate all uses!
    %2 = load i32, i32* %y, align 4
    %1 = zext i32 %2 to i64
    Instruction does not dominate all uses!
    %4 = load i32, i32* %y, align 4
    %3 = zext i32 %4 to i64
```

**Note** the fact that the inserted **zext** instructions name a constant with a counter number **less** than the previous instruction - I think this is the problem but I have no idea why my pass does this!!!

Here is the IR of my toy program before the application of the pass:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define i32 @_Z3fooi(i32 %x) #4 {
entry:
  %x.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  %y = alloca i32, align 4
  %z = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %x, i32* %x.addr, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %y, align 4
  %0 = load i32, i32* %x.addr, align 4
  %add = add nsw i32 %0, 3
  store i32 %add, i32* %y, align 4
  %1 = load i32, i32* %y, align 4
  store i32 %1, i32* %x.addr, align 4
  %2 = load i32, i32* %y, align 4
  ret i32 %2
}

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define i32 @_Z3bari(i32 %panos) #4 {
entry:
  %panos.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  %y = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %panos, i32* %panos.addr, align 4
  %0 = load i32, i32* %panos.addr, align 4
  %add = add nsw i32 %0, 2
  store i32 %add, i32* %y, align 4
  %1 = load i32, i32* %y, align 4
  ret i32 %1
}
```

Also, note that that the problematic instructions are before a terminator - Again I think that this is related.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

Your `zext` instruction uses `I`, but you're inserting it before `I`. When you create the `IRBuilder`, you should pass in the instruction after `I` as the insert point. For example like this:

```
 IRBuilder<> IRB(I->getNextNode());
```